# Why we can assign a string to a simple Java Object

Tags: java

I wonder why this is legal:

```
Object mystring = "hello";
System.out.println(mystring);
```

This prints `hello`. But why `Object` is treated like a string ?

Comment: If we look at the [Java docs for String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), we can see `public final class String
extends Object`. This means Object is the parent class of String. It's basically the same as a class `Animal` and a class `Dog extends Animal`; in which case you can do `Animal pet = new Dog();`.

Comment: `Object mystring` is a reference not an object.  You can't have Object variables in Java.

Answer (score 5):

Because a `String` IS-A `Object`, so a reference type can be any super types.

For instance, you could also assign `mystring` to a `CharSequence` type.

The `println` method of `PrintStream` (your `System.out` static field) has an overload to take `String` as an argument, and print it properly.

In this case though, the code in `PrintStream#println(Object)` will actually print `String.valueOf(x)`, where `x` is your given argument.

Answer (score 3):

It calls it's toString() method. The one that is implemented in the String class. Methods are binded at runtime.

Comment: Nit: it doesn't simply call `Object.toString()`: it first checks for `null`, and prints `"null"` in that case; otherwise, it calls `toString()`. I can't remember if it actually calls `Objects.toString(obj)`, but it's logically the same.